# How access redux-mapped props from outside a connected component

Tags: reactjs, redux

Is it possible to access redux mapped state->props in a callback after the class-based connected component is created? E.g.:

```js
// imports omitted.

class MyComp extends React.Component {
  ...
  componentDidMount() {
     this.cb();
  }
}

// dispatchToProps omitted.

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  x: state.x,
});

const ConnectedComp = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(MyComp);

// Define a callback and bind to the component
// AFTER it's created.
(() => {
  const self = ConnectedComp.prototype.constructor
    .WrappedComponent.prototype;

  self.cb = function() {
      self.props.x // FAIL: props undefined.
  }
})();

export default ConnectedComponent;
```

I assume this doesn't work because the wrapped component isn't the connected component. How do I bind to the connected component's prototype properly? I've also tried
binding to `ConnectedComp.prototype.constructor` to no avail.

Comment: I'm curios why would need todo this ?

Comment: You already have access to it when you are binding it, so why?

Answer (score 1):

This is something you really should not do in React generally - it is a very uncommon pattern that in this case is completely impossible since that "connected" component is a completely new component that only renders your component and does not extend it in any way.

An alternative suggestion would be to use another HOC to bind that callback to your component as *a prop*. And you can always call that callback with your props (or even this) as an argument instead of using `this` directly.

```js
class MyComp extends React.Component {
  ...
  componentDidMount() {
     this.cb(props);
  }
}

function withExtraProps(Component, extraProps) {
  return props => <Component {...props} {...extraProps} />
}

const ComponentWithCb = withExtraProps(ConnectedComponent, { cb: (props) => { console.log(props) } })
```

Comment: Yes, I understand the way I was trying it really "smells". I tried this and got a null props, but I will give it more time to try to figure out in the next few days.